# OAuth request_token for Etsy problem with URL construction

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, nonce, etsy

I am trying to create an app to access Etsy api using python3, I am testing my very basic code in idle3, I need to get an oauth token, I have looked at the etsy documentation [here](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth) but all is described for php.
below is my code in idle3 (I have changed my keys);

```
>>>payload = { 'api_key' : 'pvhkg9y4e7', 'shared_secret' : 'ib5msimmo', 'scope' : 'transactions_r,listings_w,billing_r,treasury_r'}

>>> url = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token"

>>> r = requests.get(url, params=payload)

>>> print(r.url)
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?api_key=pvhkg9y4e7&scope=transactions_r%2Clistings_w%2Cbilling_r%2Ctreasury_r&shared_secret=ib5msimmo

>>> r.text

>>>'oauth_problem=parameter_absent&amp;oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key%26oauth_signature%26oauth_signature_method%26oauth_nonce%26oauth_timestamp
```

I need help in creating the correct URL I think I need to change my payload wording to oauth_consumer_key, oauth_signature, but I do not understand how to include oauth_signature_method (I am using request.get) or the oauth_timestamp, and I don't know what oauth_nonce is?

I intend to incorporate the whole into a flask app, so I have looked at flask_oauth [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/) but I am not sure if this will give me the timestamp and nonce.
All advice greatly appreciated, I am following the flask tutorial by miguel grinberg, I need one like that for my etsy app! any suggestions

I also tried request_oauthlib but got this;

```
>>> from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
ImportError: No module named 'requests_oauthlib'
```

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 2):

I wrote to etsy developers, who came back with some php code, I know very little python but no PHP,
So I went back to searching google, and went back to [here](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html) and used the following code;

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
request_token_url = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/request_token?scope=transactions_r&listings_w&billing_r&treasury_r'
consumer_key = 'api_key'
consumer_secret = 'secret_key'
oauth = OAuth1(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret)
r = requests.post(url=request_token_url, auth=oauth)
r.content
```

login_url=https%6%3fthe%26address%26you%2fwant%34goodluck

and it worked!!!!!! I am so happpppy!!!
If you get any other noobs like me perhaps they can be help them with this code.

In terminal I created a virtualenv, I then pip installed requests and request_oauthlib, then in python shell executed the above script.

regards paul